# How do I change the output of the success function based on a variable using jQuery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On success, I would like to show different values depending on what value exists.  For example, if $('#add').val() has a value in it I would like to show 'Video added" as part of the success function.  If $('#remove').val() has a value in it, I would like to show 'Video removed' as part of the success function.  Either #add or #remove will have a value in it at a given time.  How do I enable this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#test").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"/edit_favorites/",
                 data: {
                        'video_add': $('#add').val(), // from form
                        'video_remove': $('#remove').val() // from form
                        },
                 success: function(){
                     $('#message').html("<h2>Video added!</h2>") 
                    }
            });
            return false;
       });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that only one of the textfields will have a value, you could do something like this:

```
$('#message').html('<h2>' + $('#add').val() !== '' ? 'Video added' : 'Video removed' + '!</h2>' )
```

Comment: Thanks Johan.  How do I interpret this statement?  I was thinking of using an if/else statement to do it.

Comment: @sharataka No problem. Its actually a short-hand version of if. Ill try to elaborate: (boolean) ? /* do stuff if bool is true */ : /* do stuff it false */. `$('#add').val() !== '' ` would evaluate as either true or false, depending on if it has a value

Answer (score 0):

if just checking text is enough you can use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#test").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"/edit_favorites/",
                 data: {
                        'video_add': $('#add').val(), // from form
                        'video_remove': $('#remove').val() // from form
                        },
                 success: function(){
                     if ( $('#add').text() ) {
                        $('#message').html("<h2>Video added!</h2>");
                     } else if ( $('#add').text() ){
                        $('#message').html("<h2>Video removed!</h2>");
                     } else {
                        $('#message').html("<h2>Wasn't either add or remove!</h2>");
                     }
                    }
            });
            return false;
       });

    });
</script>
```

I assumed `#add` or `#remove` are text. The key is this `if` check:

```
if ( $('#add').text() ) {
   //... add is not empty because there is some text in it...
```

If `#add` or `#remove` may contain text or any other element, you can check them with `:empty` selector:

```
if ( !$('#add:empty').length ) {
   //... #add is not empty so something was added successfully ...
```

If `#add` or `#remove` are `<input>` elements like text box you can do the same check with:

```
if ( $('#add').val() ) {
   //... add is not empty ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to return a response when the backend script has executed, XML would look something like this

```
 <status>true</status>
 <successMessage>Video deleted</successMessage>
```

or

```
<status>false</status>
<errorMessage>Video not found on the server</errorMessage>
```

Javascript

```
success: function (response) {
   if($(response).find("status").text()=="true"){
        $(".success").html($(response).find("successMessage").text());
        $(".success").show();
   }else{
        $(".error").html($(response).find("errorMessage").text());
        $(".error").show();
   }
}
```